# How to prevent user to send multiple Checkout of the same cart in Magento 2

Tags: session, magento2, cart, checkout, quote

How can I prevent user to checkout 1 cart Session using multiple tabs or multiple browser?

By default, while the last checkout step is still loading, a user can resubmit the same cart multiple times until 1 process is completed resulting to duplicate orders.

Any thoughts on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from your custom module. Maybe you didn't call an ajax attribute or the loading part. By default Magento when you click on checkout button then you can't click other buttons anymore because there will be a loading section appear on the page.

To check you can disable all payment modules and use the default Magento payment method